# Collapsed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with numerous collapsable panels.

Example Panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-flat">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h6 class="panel-title">Next of Kin details</h6>
    <div class="heading-elements">
        <ul class="icons-list">
            <li><a data-action="collapse"></a></li>
            <li><a data-action="reload"></a></li>
            <li><a data-action="close"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
```

I would like this panel to be collapsed when the page loads, is this possible?

Comment: Sure it is, what have **you** tried?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".